# In relation to acumatica, is there a way to grab a variable from one table and use it as part of an id for another table?

Tags: c#, acumatica

The 'Customer' form has a variable called AcctReferenceNbr ([Variable that I'm trying to grab shown in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjO7n.jpg)) which takes a two-letter abbreviation of the customer name. I am currently editing the Projects form, and I want to use this abbreviation as part of the External Ref. Nbr.

The attached image [End Result I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ojBi.jpg) shows what the end result should look like. The number from the QuoteID is appended to the abbreviation.

I am able to successfully grab the QuoteID as it is part of the Projects table, but I am currently unable to grab the AcctReference Nbr from the Customer table.

I have a RowSelected event on the QuoteID field, which is shown below:

```
    namespace PX.Objects.PM
    {
      public class ProjectEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ProjectEntry>
      {
        #region Event Handlers
    
        
        protected void PMProject_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
          
          PMProject row = (PMProject)e.Row;
          if (row.ContractCD != null) {
            PMProject item = PXSelectorAttribute.Select<PMProject.contractCD>(cache, row) as PMProject;
            
            // The "UP" string is where the abbreviation is supposed to be, 
            // but I just added two letters to test if the appending works, which it does.
    
            row.ExtRefNbr = "UP" + item.ContractCD;
          }
          
        }
    
        #endregion
      }
    }
```

What I've tried so far:

- Accessing the Customer table namespace to grab the value and pass it to the Projects form, which didn't work because it didn't accept the Customer type in the Projects form.
- Adding a PXDefault attribute to the External Ref. Nbr which would try and grab the variable using SQL.

I'm a bit stuck on what else I can try. Any help would be appreciated :)

**UPDATED**

Below is how I went about trying to grab the AcctReferenceNbr value from the Customer table.

The reason why I tried using the PXSelectorAttribute method was that I added the AcctReferenceNbr as a column to the Quote ID selector (selector is shown in the link above called 'End Result I'm trying to achieve').

So I figured I could try and grab that value in the Customer namespace, as that is where the variable resides, and pass that up to the Project namespace above.

Then, I would call the public method below in the Project namespace to get the required abbreviation:

```
// instead of this
row.ExtRefNbr = "UP" + item.ContractCD;

// it would be this
row.ExtRefNbr = PX.Objects.AR.CustomerMaint_Extension.getAcctReferenceNbr(cache, e) + item.ContractCD;
```

```
    namespace PX.Objects.AR
    {
      public class CustomerMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CustomerMaint>
      {
        #region Event Handlers
    
        public static string getAcctReferenceNbr(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
          
            BAccount row = (BAccount)e.Row;
          
            BAccount item = PXSelectorAttribute.Select<BAccount.acctReferenceNbr>(cache, row) as BAccount;
    
            return item.acctReferenceNbr;
          }
          
        }
    
        #endregion
      }
    }
```

Is there a proper way to target the actual table?

Comment: can you share your code where you're accessing the Customer table ?

Comment: I'm not currently accessing the Customer table as the code I wrote didn't work, so I just removed that part of the code. Did you want me to send through what my attempt to access it looked like?

Comment: yes. cause that's the way to go. and i'm curious why its not working for you.

Comment: I've added an update, let me know if you need me to clarify anything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. I haven't tested this but give it a go.

```
    protected void PMProject_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
      
      PMProject row = (PMProject)e.Row;
      if (row.ContractCD != null && row.CustomerID != null) 
      {

        BAccount ba = (BAccount )PXSelectorAttribute.Select<PMProject.customerID>(cache, row) ;    
        row.ExtRefNbr = ba.AcctReferenceNbr+ row.ContractCD;
      }
      
    }
```

you certainly don't need to extend the CustomerMaint graph.

Comment: Sorry for the wait Rick, it might be a couple of days until I get a chance to try it out. I'll let you know how I go. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Hey Rick, I tried it out earlier today, and it worked perfectly! Thanks so much for your help! :)